# copula-marginal algorithm

Tags: risk-management, copula

has there been any interesting work or advances on the copula-marginal algorithm (CMA) as proposed by 
Attilio Meucci. I am unable to find anything on the web other then the original article, here is the [original article](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1752702) that i am referring too. I'm just curious if any one has built on his research or if this may be of any use at all

Answer (score 6):

The algorithm is certainly useful in that it is non-parametric, fast, and versatile. [Meucci](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1752702) summarizes the advantages nicely:

> Unlike traditional copula techniques, CMA a) is not restricted to few
>   parametric copulas such as elliptical or Archimedean; b) never
>   requires the explicit computation of marginal cdf’s or quantile
>   functions; c) does not assume equal probabilities for all the
>   scenarios, and thus allows for advanced techniques such as importance
>   sampling or entropy pooling; d) allows for arbitrary transformations
>   of copulas. Furthermore, the implementation of CMA is also
>   computationally very efficient in arbitrary large dimensions.

The paper was published 3Q last year so there are not many citations yet. Hard to see what features are lacking -- if anything, the algorithm corrects for the weaknesses of parametric copulas and offers far more versatility for stress-testing and mixing arbitrary copulas and marginals.

Comment: Is it possible to give more citation that Meucci's article as requested in the question? This will be very much appreciated.